# When selecting the radio button for title value of radio button should added to the input text box

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/45756/

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr." checked>Mr.
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs.">Mrs.
    <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 

</div>



// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function(gender) {

    this.lastName = ko.observable(gender);

    this.firstName = ko.computed(function() {

        return this.gender() +  this.firstname();
    }, this);
};
```

When any click the radio button Mr. and Mrs should added in front of text box of first name.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
var ViewModel = function(gender) {

  this.lastName = ko.observable(gender);

  this.firstName = ko.computed(function() {

    return this.gender() + this.firstname();
  }, this);
};


function putMr() {
  document.getElementById('textField').value = 'Mr.';
}

function putMrs() {
  document.getElementById('textField').value = 'Mrs.';
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr." checked onclick="putMr()">Mr.
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs." onclick="putMrs()">Mrs.


<p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' id="textField" /></p>
```

I'm using the `onclick` method on the radio buttons, then couple a JS function to it which appends the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code at "http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/45804/". Please see it.

change js as:

```
function setGender(obj){
document.getElementById('set_value').value = obj.value;
console.log(obj.value);

}
```

and input field as:

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' id="set_value"/></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/45804/

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this question with the knockout tag.  But your fiddle is wrong.

I updated your view model:

a)  `this.lastName = ko.observable(gender);` should be  `this.gender = ko.observable(gender);`

b) I changed `this.firstName = ko.computed ...` to an observable `this.firstName = ko.observable('');`

And You forgot to apply bindings: `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel('m'));`
Also, in your fiddle you need to add jQuery because Knockout needs it.

That is:

```
var ViewModel = function(gender) {

    this.gender = ko.observable(gender);
    this.firstName = ko.observable('');

    this.fullData = ko.computed(function() {           
        return this.gender() + ' ' + this.firstName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel('m'));
```

And:

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr." checked>Mr.
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs.">Mrs.
    <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 

</div>
```

Now, change the radio buttons to use the [checked binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr."  data-bind="checked: gender"> Mr.
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs." data-bind="checked: gender"> Mrs.
```

With this, your view model gets updated when you click in the radio buttons.

The last thing to do is show the value of `gender` adding `<span data-bind="text:gender"></span>`:

```
<p>First name: <span data-bind="text:gender"></span><input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p>
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/45819/).